# sufficient condition for a series of complex numbers to converge absolutely

Tags: complex-analysis

if the series of complex numbers $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} z_n$ converges and there is a number $ 0 < \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2} $ such that for all $ n \in \Bbb N$ it is verify that $ | arg (z_n) |<\alpha $, then said series absolutely converges.

here $|arg (z_n)|$ is the main argument of the complex number.

Comment: I don't think your comparison makes sense. For the series to converge absolutely, you need $|z_n| \to 0$. Since this has to happen at some point, we may assume that eventually $|z_n|<1$. Then it follows that  $|z_n|^2<|z_n|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write each $z_n=r_ne^{Arg(z_n)i}$ with $-\pi<Arg(z_n)\leq \pi$. Then since the series converges, the real part must converge. The assumption $|Arg(z_n)|<\alpha<\pi/2$ guarantees that each $Re(z_n)>0$, and in fact,
$$
r_n\cos(\alpha)<r_n\cos(Arg(z_n))=Re(z_n).
$$
Since $\sum Re(z_n)$ converges, by comparison, it follows that $\sum r_n\cos(\alpha)=\cos(\alpha)\sum r_n$ converges so $\sum r_n$ converges. Obviously, $\sum |z_n|=\sum r_n$ must converge.

Comment: I think that you have a mistake here $r_n\cos(\alpha)<r_n\cos(Arg(z_n))$ 
how do you deduce that?

Comment: if you have this $|Arg(z_n)|<\alpha$ you can't conclude this $r_n\cos(\alpha)<r_n\cos(Arg(z_n))$

Comment: Why not? $|Arg(z_n)|<\alpha<\pi/2 \implies -\pi/2<-\alpha<Arg(z_n)<\alpha<\pi/2$. Then $\cos(x)$ is achieves a minimum at $x=\alpha$ on the interval $[-\alpha,\alpha]$. $r_n$ is just a fixed positive number. I guess it could be nonnegative and the strict inequalities become normal inequalities.

Comment: Is it possible the confusion is that what you are calling $arg$, I am calling $Arg$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: we then have $\operatorname{Re}{z_n} \geq \frac{1}{\tan{\alpha}}|\operatorname{Im}{z_n}|$.

Answer (score 0):

$\arg(z_n)\in]-\alpha,\alpha[$ thus $\cos(\arg(z_n))\geqslant\cos(\alpha)$ and $|z_n|\leqslant|z_n|\frac{\cos(\arg(z_n))}{\cos(\alpha)}=\frac{\text{Re}(z_n)}{\cos(\alpha)}$ but $\sum\text{Re}(z_n)$ converges so $\sum|z_n|$ converges.